# Scroll to a div left of body

Tags: html, css, scroll

I want to make a horizontal scroll website with `#page1` positioned left of `body` with `position:absolute; right:100%;`

**Why can't I access this "page" by scrolling left**.

On this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/NCe7W/2/)** you can see that `#page2` can be scrolled to but not `#page1`.

What would be the solution to have this page on the left on page load?

HTML :

```
<section id="home">Home</section>
<section id="page1">Page 1</section>
<section id="page2">Page 2</section>
```

CSS :

```
html,body,section{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
section{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
#page1{
    right:100%;
}
#page2{
    left:100%;
}
```

Comment: Right now, home is covering Page 1. See Stuart Kershaw's answer for a working implementation.

Comment: @TylerH well, when I inspect with chrome dv tools, I can see page 1 on the left of home.

Comment: Home isn't technically covering Page 1; Page 1 is to the left of home (as he intends), it just can't be scrolled to. You can see this by [lowering Page 1's `right` percentage a bit](http://jsfiddle.net/NCe7W/7/).

Answer (score 2):

The question is a little confusing, so I'm not sure if this is what you're after... But to align these elements from left to right, you can use the following: http://jsfiddle.net/NCe7W/4/

```
#page1{ left: 100%; }
#page2{ left: 200%; }
```

If you want to alter the order of the elements you could do so by altering the left values of each element. Something like: http://jsfiddle.net/NCe7W/9/

```
#home { left: 100%; }
#page1{ left: 0; }
#page2{ left: 200%; }
```

Comment: My aim is to have `#page1` on the left of `#home`.

Comment: Ok, in that case you can either just reorder the elements so that `#page1` is left of `#home` with styling / CSS.

Comment: Updated my answer above, and new fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/NCe7W/9/ - this requires no JS.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a way to initially load a page that is already halfway scrolled without JavaScript. It sounds like this is what you'd like to do: load the page with "home" visible, but allow scrolling left to "page1" or right to "page2".

A relatively simple way to achieve that with minimal JavaScript is:

1. Set `window.location.hash` to the ID of your home div on page load
2. Set page1 to `left:0`, home to `left:100%`, and page2 to `left:200%`.

Here's a [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/NCe7W/6/).

Comment: yes, I like this solution too but how come can't `#page1` be accessed when it is on the left of body?

Comment: I don’t know the “official” answer to this (someone else might be able to link to a spec somewhere), but if it was accessible, it would create a situation where either the page would need to start halfway scrolled or it would start scrolled all the way left, in which case the body’s “left” wouldn’t actually start where it predictably should (on the left). Both situations seem strange and undesirable in most cases... so maybe someone somewhere decided to ignore things that are positioned off to the left. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I could rearrange your code, but I am going to stick to answering your question in it's current state. You could position your `sections` similar to as you are currently and then with 2 lines of lightweight javascript code (not jQuery library) you could then center to your required page

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/NCe7W/10/

```
var el = document.getElementById('home');
    el.scrollIntoView(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of absolutely positioning these, I would set the `body` to `width: 300%` and the `section`'s to `width: 33.33%` and float the `section`'s. See this codepen demo http://codepen.io/the_ruther4d/pen/623a19f2e71a9ecb881400fe887c04f0/